# Embed images within a block of text on iPad

Tags: ipad, uitextview

I would like to embed an image within a block of text. The image would be 1 line high. I am able to drag the image around over the text but I want to be able to insert it between words (with the words wrapping in the textview accordingly)

Any ideas how I can go about this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try to use CoreText, and create text boxes on all four sides of the image.

http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Carbon/Conceptual/CoreText_Programming/Introduction/Introduction.html